Dataform cross project dependencies
Currently in dataform , the dependencies can be specified either intra-repository or cross-repository. I'd like to specify some dependencies that rely on a dataform repository in a different project. I tried specifying the full name in the dependencies field in config object but it did not compile.
One option is to use code and stitch the workflow together with APIs and some orchestration layer , but is there a way to do this directly in SQLX? That would be much simpler.

Hi @Raghuveer, Can you check the following documentation which might be helpful.
